# Python tKinter EventLoop pauses calls to after() - MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm finding that if I use `root.after()` to make a function repeat, but then click on a menu or launch a dialog, it will stop repeating until the dialog or menu is closed.

This is not the behaviour I want - I would like the function to keep repeating, even when the menu or dialog is open.

Could someone tell me if this is expected behaviour, and if so, if there is a way to stop it?

Sample code:

```
def repeater():
    print("repeating")
    root.after(500, repeater)

root.after(500, repeater)
root.showerror("Error", "Error")
```

---EDIT---

Sorry, had no access to a dev environment, so couldn't give full code example.
This on MAC OSX, in Python 3.6

Here's a full code sample:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, messagebox

def msg():
    print("repeating")
    root.after(500, msg)

def pop():
    messagebox.showinfo( "Block", "Blocking...")

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Pop", command=pop).pack()
root.after(500, msg)
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I click the button, or click any of the OSX menus - it stops printing the message...

--- EDIT 2 ---
I've been able to get access to a Raspberry Pi - and test this code on there. It works fine, the popUp does not stop the message from being printed out. It's therefore starting to look like a Mac OSX issue - specifically El Capitan, 10.11.6

From the comments on the original post - it seems like this code also works fine on Windows.

Can anyone else test it on OSX, to confirm it's a problem?

Comment: >Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that(**delay_ms**); if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer. [link](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)

Comment: what does your `showerror` function do? Is that one of the standard dialogs? What platform are you running on? Is this code literally the code you use? It's missing a call to `mainloop` -- are you calling `mainloop`, and do you call it before or after calling `showerror`?

Comment: When I make reasonable assumptions about the missing code, your code works fine for me on linux. `repeater` is called continuously while the dialog is open.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on Win too. `tk.Menu` and `tk.filedialog` doesn't block repeating! Can you show runnable code so we can play around with it?

Comment: I've added code above - definitely not working on my MacBook... could someone test it out?